# Table view is crashed when collapsing the cell in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Table view is crashed when collapsing the cell in iOS7 with error message:

```
- Assertion failure in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:]

- 'Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction'.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Try returning 0 instead of anything else in following method and it won't crash anymore.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //return 0.001f;
      return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

there are few things lead to this carash on iOS7

- UITableViewStyle
- header/footerViewHeight

to sove this problem:

can you try:

one:

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

two:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug.  I discovered changing the table style to grouped stops the crashing:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) 
    {

    }
    return self;
```

}

Alternately you can change the stele in the storyboard.